# How to save Fragment state across orientation changes using FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm using a `ViewPager` with a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and I'm having problems saving the Fragment's state across orientation changes. It works fine when paging back and forth e.g. viewing a page, swiping two pages away, and then going back 2 pages to the original Fragment correctly saves and restores state. I am doing this using `onSaveInstanceState` and restoring state in `onCreateView` if the `Bundle` isn't null.

Changing orientations, however, doesn't work through the same mechanism and from my testing doesn't even call the fragment's `onSaveInstanceState` method.

Is this expected? Am I missing something to force it to save instance state? Did I do something to stop it from working?

Thanks!

Comment: My experience tells me to save everything to permanent storage and use that instead :) but it should work for rotations as well =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't calling `super.onSaveInstanceState()` in the `Activity` so none of the `ViewPager`/`Fragment` state was maintained. Adding in `super.onSaveInstanceState()` fixed it!